# How can we groupby selected row values from a column and assign it to a new column in pandas df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

```
Id  B
1   6
2   13
1   6
2   6
1   6
2   6
1   10
2   6
2   6
2   6
```

I want a new columns say `C` where I can get a grouped value of `B=6` at `Id` level

```
Jan18.loc[Jan18['Enquiry Purpose']==6].groupby(Jan18['Member Reference']).transform('count')
```

```
Id  B   No_of_6
1   6   3
2   13  5
1   6   3
2   6   5
1   6   3
2   6   5
1   10  3
2   6   5
2   6   5
2   6   5
```

Answer (score 3):

Comapre values by [`Series.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.eq.html) for `==`, convert to integers and use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) for new column filled by `sum` per groups:

```
df['No_of_6'] = df['B'].eq(6).astype(int).groupby(df['Id']).transform('sum')
#alternative
#df['No_of_6'] = df.assign(B= df['B'].eq(6).astype(int)).groupby('Id')['B'].transform('sum')
print (df)
   Id   B  No_of_6
0   1   6        3
1   2  13        5
2   1   6        3
3   2   6        5
4   1   6        3
5   2   6        5
6   1  10        3
7   2   6        5
8   2   6        5
9   2   6        5
```

Generally create boolean mask by your condition(s) and pass below:

```
mask = df['B'].eq(6)
#alternative
#mask = (df['B'] == 6)
df['No_of_6'] = mask.astype(int).groupby(df['Id']).transform('sum')
```

Comment: What if I want to use multiple conditions, like B=6 & B = 5 | B = 7?

Comment: @Abhaykumar - added generally solution - only change `mask` like you need

Comment: @jottbe - No, because pandas devs working with bugs in pandas 0.25, so no time answering. ;) For me is coding like hobby ;)

Answer (score 0):

A solution using `map`. This solution will return `NaN` on groups of `Id` have no number of `6`

```
df['No_of_6'] = df.Id.map(df[df.B.eq(6)].groupby('Id').B.count())

Out[113]:
   Id   B  No_of_6
0   1   6        3
1   2  13        5
2   1   6        3
3   2   6        5
4   1   6        3
5   2   6        5
6   1  10        3
7   2   6        5
8   2   6        5
9   2   6        5
```